# Can we convert resource adapter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss-eap-7, kodo

We are working on a migration project. The orignal application would use kodo jdo rar as the connection adapter to have persistent while connecting to db. The rar file has to seperatly deployed separately from the application ear. Also the jars used by the application are loaded from module class loading policies of jboss eap 7. But have to be shared by both ear and the rar this is causing locking of the calsses  when application is being undeployed and would not allow clean re deployment of the application. Until the server restart.

So can we convert kodo rar to jar so it can be loaded in the application as a single part.

The kodo rar exposes jndi connection with which our application  (ear) interacts

I have  searched  for a conversion. I do know rar files are for resources adapter by j2ca standards.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Let me known if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.